# how to validate html text field using java script to ensure no more than one word contain in text field

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to validate or ensure that user inputs just one word in my HTML text field using JavaScript. Any help?

Comment: maybe this link can help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18679576/counting-words-in-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose if user string is say in javascript variable

```
var input; // store user input
```

then use string split function on white space

```
var len =input.split(" ");
```

then if lenght of array 'len' is greater than 1 that means user entered more than one word.

```
if(len.length > 1)
// print message
```

Comment: Better use `input.split(/\s/);`

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<form action="" method='post'>
        <input type='text' name='my-field' id='my-field' />
        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' />
</form>

<script>
    var element = document.getElementById('my-field');

    element.onblur = function() {
        var value = element.value.trim();

        if (value.indexOf(' ') > -1 ) {
            alert('do not use space');
            element.focus();
        }
     }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And, [with out using alert refer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21822324/javascript-form-validation-without-alert)